# Assign value to checkbox in JQgrid

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

For the below command I am getting checkboxes for first column

```
 {   label: 'Request Id', 
     name: 'RequestId', 
     searchoptions: { 
         sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'gt', 'lt', 'ge', 'le'], 
         optDescriptions: { eq: 'my eq', gt: 'after', le: 'on or before' } 
     }
 },                      
 multiselect: true
```

Need to assign RequestId value to checkbox.